# Syntax error when declaring a list of characters in java

Tags: java

I'm not really sure what's the problem, when I try to declare a new list like that:

```
List<Character> newLst = ArrayList<Character>();
```

and the compiler tells me *"Syntax error on token "(", Expression expected after this token"*.
I declared a list of Integers like that:

```
List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

and I have no problems, what did I do wrong?

Comment: You need a `new` keyword: `List<Character> newLst = new ArrayList<Character>();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A constructor is called with the `new` operator:

```
List<Character> newLst = new ArrayList<Character>();
```

Comment: Wow, how come I didn't notice that? My bad, I am too tired, I will go to sleep, thank you.